# Send enter key in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Im not trying to capture if a user clicked enter or not.
What I am trying to do is send an enter key in javascript.

I have an asp.net textbox:

`<asp:TextBox id="myBox" runat="server" OnChange="SendEnter" />`

On any key press in this text box I want it to call a client side function called "SendEnter".

In send enter I want to send the enter keystroke (this is not to submit a form but to fire the server side OnChanged event of the asp.net textbox).

Can I do something like:

```
function SendEnter() {
 var theKey = 13; //enter key?
 document.trigger(13);  //not sure if this even exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to simulate the event:

[Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

The important thing is to pay attention to the keycode that represents the Enter:

```
press.which = 13;
```